# Prevent text from sticking out of the screen

Tags: react-native, text, screen, listitem, react-native-elements

I have a list of products that I make using React native elements ListItem. So far, everything is fine, except that the field 'ListItem.Title' is too long as you can see in the screenshot below. I would like to know how I can do so that it does not protrude from the screen, so that the line break is done automatically, or even add a small margin so that it can be more aesthetic. Could you give me your opinion, your advice? Thank you for your help and explanations.

```
<ListItem key={i} 
        bottomDivider 
        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('ProductDetails', {productId: parseInt(item.id)})}>
    <Icon name='flight-takeoff' />  
    <ListItem.Title>{item.name}</ListItem.Title>
       <ListItem.Subtitle style={{ color: '#F78400' }}>
          {i18n.t("information.cost")}: {item.price}
       </ListItem.Subtitle>                  
</ListItem>
```

[image]

Thank you a lot @Ashwith Saldanha for taking the time to answer. I followed your advices but it was not completely resolving the problem I got.
I tried :

> <ListItem.Title style={{width: '100%'}}>{item.name}</ListItem.Title>

This gives exactly the same thing that I had before.

Then, i used your other alternative:

> <ListItem.Title numberOfLines={1}>{item.name}</ListItem.Title>

Giving :
[image: one line]

It's not really what i was looking for. Finally, I did this but I'm not sure it's the cleaner way to resolve the problem, moreover I would have liked the subtitle to be under the title it's weird:

```
<ListItem key={i} 
     bottomDivider 
     onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('ProductDetails', {productId: parseInt(item.id)})}>
     <Icon name='flight-takeoff' />  
     <ListItem.Title style={{width: '75%'}}>{item.name}</ListItem.Title>
     <ListItem.Subtitle style={{ color: '#F78400'}}>
          {i18n.t("information.cost")}: {item.cost}
      </ListItem.Subtitle>
```

This gives me this result :

[image: 75%]

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 solutions which i got from reading your question

1. use can use numberOfLines prop to break the text if it is set to one text will break at 1 line

`<ListItem.Title numberOfLines={1}>`

[image]

if you want to break the text at 2 lines set it to to

2. set style property

`<ListItem.Title style={{width: '100%'}}>`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It didn't resolve completely the problem but it helps a lot. thanks a lot. I edited my post to add what I changed thanks to you !